# How to link website to several media queries?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I want to style my HTML differently according to different media queries. For example, I want my HTML to display in a way when it is viewed on a browser with a width of 1024px or less, and in another way if it is viewed on a browser with a landscape orientation (like when a phone is flipped over). Here is what I tried doing;

```css
@media (max-width: 1024px) {
 h1{
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
}

@media (orientation: landscape) {
 h1{
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <body>
           <h1>Hello world</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

But unfortunately it didn't work. The problem was that when I loaded the site on a landscape device the code did not change.

Note: My problem is *not* that the media queries are completely not functioning. It is, however that I am being unable to use *more than two* media queries.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm seeing a number of questions on this site regarding "media queries not responding to orientation". Have you looked at those? For instance: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20199764/215552, http://stackoverflow.com/q/17637833/215552, http://stackoverflow.com/q/20026904/215552.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a beginning, try to use this instead of what you have:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {...
```

Comment: Ok. I have edited my code. What should I do now?  Thanks

Comment: well, write media queries for different screen widths (and be careful to write them in a meaningful order: It wouldn't make sense to beginn with `max-width: 768px,`  and then add a section for "max-width: 1024px` since the second one will override the first (i.e. a 600px wide screen is both below 768 and below 1024px wide). So in this example you'd have to do it in the opposite order.  (Note: I don't know what your exact problem is, so I can't be more specific - you have to post your code and describe the exact problem if you want more than a general answer...)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked, I believe. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: You are welcome! Sol, how about marking the question as correct or voting it up then?

Comment: I marked it as correct, but since I don't have enough rep. points, my upvotes will not be publicly displayed.